# What is the difference between name() and local-name()?

Tags: xml, xpath

I don't really understand the difference between the XPath functions [`name`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-name) and [`local-name`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-local-name).

Could you give an example of a situation where they would differ?

### Edit

Given this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head></head>
</html>
```

I get the same result with these two queries: `//*[local-name()="head"]` and `//*[name()="head"]`. Why is that?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

With the XML being

```
<x:html xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>
```

the stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <local-name><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></local-name>
    <name><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></name>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

outputs

```
<local-name>html</local-name>
<name>x:html</name>
```

So the `local-name()` result is without any prefix, `the name()` result might include a prefix.

In your sample with a default namespace declaration no prefix is present, therefore `name()` and `local-name()` give the same result.

Comment: If your stylesheet includes the xhtml namespace with different prefix, name() outputs the prefix in input XML. What if I want the prefix to be the one defined in the stylesheet?

Comment: There are namespace nodes on the namespace axis and in XSLT/XPath 2.0 there are functions to operate on and resolve namespaces or find prefixes like http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-in-scope-prefixes which of course can be applied to nodes in the stylesheet as well. You can get hold of the document node of your stylesheet using `document('')`. Ask a question on your own if you need more explanation on that.

Comment: Hi, I've asked a question on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811344/how-to-get-namespace-prefix-as-defined-in-stylesheet-and-not-from-input-xml