# How to get namespace prefix as defined in stylesheet and not from input XML

Tags: xslt, xml-namespaces

I have this input XML:

```
<x:html xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>
```

and I am using the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:y="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output I am getting is (root element with prefix `x`, as defined in input XML)

```
x:html
```

The output I expect is (root element with prefix `y`, as defined in the XSLT):

```
y:html
```

Comment: Your output method is text. The result you are getting is a string, it does not really have a namespace prefix. You can remove the "prefix" by getting the value-of local-name() instead, then add your own using a string manipulation - assuming you really want to do all of this in the text domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look on the [namepace axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#namespace-nodes) of the root element of your XSLT code e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:y="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="xslt-root" select="document('')/*"/>
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name($xslt-root/namespace::*[. = namespace-uri(current())]), ':', local-name())"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```