# How to exclude elements from xpath result

Tags: xpath

Hi I know this is quite basic but I wasn't able to find the answer by myself.

In this example:

```
<root>
   <a/>
   <b/>
   <c/>
   <d/>
</root>
```

I want to select all `root` children except `b` and `d`.

I wrote something like this that didn't work.

```
/root/*[not(b) and not(d)]
```

the result is all the root children: `a,b,c,d`.
How to select only `a` and `c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I want to select all root children except `b` and `d`"*

Your attempted XPath missed `self` axis :

```
/root/*[not(self::b) and not(self::d)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct xpath is `/root/*[name() != 'b' and name() != 'c']`, i checked the name of the node

Answer (score 1):

If you're using XPath 2.0, you can use the following, which maybe is a bit shorter and easier to read if you have to update your list of exclusions:

`/root/*[not(name() = ('b', 'c'))]`

This takes advantage of XPath 2.0's `=` operator on sequences, which returns `true` if there is one equal pair of items in the compared sequences. So if an element's `name()` is either `'b'` or `'c'`, the comparison is `true`, and then you want to exclude the node (hence the `not()`).

Also, check [What is the difference between name() and local-name()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462248/what-is-the-difference-between-name-and-local-name/2464906) to see if you should use `name()` or `local-name()`. In most cases, what people actually want is `local-name()`.