# Can't parse data from `th` tag along with `td` tag from different tables

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I've written a script in python using `xpath` to parse tabular data from a webpage. Upon execution, it is able to parse the data from tables flawlessly. The only thing that I can't fix is parse the `table header` that means `th` tag. If I would do the same using css selector, i could have used `.cssselect("th,td")` but in case of `xpath` I got stuck. Any help as to how I could parse the data from `th` tag also will be highly appreciated.

Here is the script which is able to fetch everything from different tables except for the data within `th` tag:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

response = requests.get("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/player-list/")
tree = fromstring(response.text)
for row in tree.xpath("//*[@class='ism-table']//tr"):
    tab_d = row.xpath('.//td/text()')
    print(tab_d)
```

Comment: What is desired output? Do you want to get th nodes along with td from each tr?

Comment: Apology in advance to both of the xpath giants who care to provide me with excellent solutions. It's hard to choose a solution over the other. However, I'm considering  as my selected answer the one I've got first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I get your point, but if you want to fetch both `th` and `td` nodes with single XPath, you can try to replace

```
tab_d = row.xpath('.//td/text()')
```

with

```
tab_d = row.xpath('.//*[name()=("th" or "td")]/text()')
```

Comment: A little clarity would be much appreciated on how the term `name`appear within the xpath out of nowhere @ sir Andersson.

Comment: [`name()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/name) (or [`local-name()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462248/what-is-the-difference-between-name-and-local-name)) might be used to check string representation of node name

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
.//td/text()
```

to

```
.//*[self::td or self::th]/text()
```

to include `th` elements too.

Note that it would be reasonable to assume that both `td` and `th` are immediate children of the `tr` context node, so you might further simplify your XPath to this:

```
*[self::td or self::th]/text()
```

Comment: Thanks sir kjhughes for your solution. It did the trick flawlessly as well. This is the first time I came across this term `self` within any xpath. I'm not sure I'll understand this style myself. +1 for your effective solution.