# How to identify the classname or id in Python Scraping with beautifulsoup and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am building a scraper code and already have been able to read the table and the information that I want. The problem is with the next page link, I have tried using a class name and also and svg tag but the code breaks as the value of the class name changes.

Here is the link of the page

[Page to scrape](https://super.walmart.com.mx/despensa/enlatados-y-conservas/chiles-enlatados/_/N-10kldy7)

And the code for the element css that the code runs to click for next page is this

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#root > div > div > main > div.ez6st4XksKUGZfGdvIhjV > section > div:nth-child(1) > div._1c5cPqlj4FoguvpKXSY69p > div > span:nth-child(3) > svg').click()
```

It seems that when the value of the class name changes it breaks and changes the element to click and I havent found a way to repeat without changing the element in order to repeat for multiple pages with the same structure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below line to click Next button without referring to dynamic class names:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@value]/following-sibling::span/*[name()="svg"]').click()
```

The same with CSS-selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span[value] + span > svg')
```

*Update*

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

while True:
    try:
        wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[value] + span > svg'))).click()
    except:
        break
```

Comment: I'm still unable to figure out how this `name()` works @sir Andersson. Does it only work with tags?

Comment: @SIM `svg` (and all it's possible descendants) is not from [HTML namespace](https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/), but from [SVG namespace](https://www.w3.org/2000/svg), so you cannot use just `//svg` to locate it. You should use `//*[name()="svg"]`. Also it works for attributes. For instance, `//@*[name()="id"]`. Note that in CSS-selector you can locate `svg` as common element...

Comment: The way you create xpath is enviable sir. However, the thing is I didn't find any link where I can learn about the usage of `name()` function. Thanks.

Comment: @SIM yeah, the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/name) is not informative at all :) You can just remember that if you work with the different namespaces, `name` function is what you need. Note that there is `local-name` function also which works [almost in the same way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462248/what-is-the-difference-between-name-and-local-name)

Comment: Thank you Andersson, acutally the code breaks at half ot the process in page 4 rather than keep going to page 6

Comment: @sputnikk1093 , welcome! You can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) answer if it solved your problem/[upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) if it was useful

Answer (score 2):

As you can click the span you can also use

```
from selenium import webdriver
d  = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://super.walmart.com.mx/despensa/enlatados-y-conservas/chiles-enlatados/_/N-10kldy7?%2Fdespensa%2Fenlatados-y-conservas%2Fchiles-enlatados%2F_%2FN-10kldy7%3F%2Fdespensa%2Fenlatados-y-conservas%2Fchiles-enlatados%2F_%2FN-10kldy7%3F%2Fdespensa%2Fenlatados-y-conservas%2Fchiles-enlatados%2F_%2FN-10kldy7%3FNs=product.displayText%7C0&offSet=0&storeId=0000009999&No=40'
d.get(url)
# example number of clicks below
for i in range(2):
    d.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@d,'M0')]/parent::*/parent::span").click()
```